# search for matching variable into two columns Yii

Tags: yii, conditional-statements, criteria, tablecolumn

I have  p1 and p2 in my db and a variable `$product`.
`$product` can either be in p1 or p2 but not both.
Not sure if this what I should be using:

```
$criteria->addColumnCondition(array('p1'=>$prod_id, 'p2'=>$prod_id),'OR');
```

Only p1 shows correctly, and p2 doesn't display anything. p2 should show exactly like p1.

Comment: What is p1 and p2? product id?

Comment: Why not using addCondition() ? Try this : $criteria->addCondition(array('p1'=>$prod_id, 'p2'=>$prod_id),'OR');

Comment: Ahh I had your way wrong before so I thought it didn't work. Thanks Jack!

Comment: What is it exactly in SQL syntax? And why don't you write `$criteria->condition='p1 =:prod_id OR p2=:prod_id'; $criteria->params=array(':prod_id'=>$prod_id);`